# Issue in Sagemaker XGBoost Model

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to build an XGBoost model in Sagemaker Studio. But while training I am getting the following error. Can someone tell me what the issue is regarding?

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job demo-xgboost-venn-2024-02-05-11-57-23-767: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/*trainer.py", line 84, in train
entrypoint()
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 94, in main
train(framework.training_env())
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 90, in train
run_algorithm_mode()
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 68, in run_algorithm_mode
checkpoint_config=checkpoint_config
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/train.py", line 105, in sagemaker_train
train_dmatrix, val_dmatrix = get_validated_dmatrices(train_path, val_path, file_type, csv_weights, is_pipe)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/train.py", line 61, in get_validated_dmatrices
if train_files*

I am looking for a solution to the above problem

Comment: How does your pipeline look like? It's hard to tell where the error is coming from without a bit more context.

Comment: You need to add more context to your question but you can check your input data; make sure that there is no inf or nan in your data.